# Loop through array and create a ListItem for each item

Tags: arrays, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to loop through the array passed in named tools and create a ListItem for each item in the list based on its properties. Currently all I have being displayed is my ListSubheader. No Buttons display. I would like to confirm that my problem is here rather than what is being passed down.

tools looks like:

```
[
   {
      icon: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      route: PropTypes.string.isRequired 
   }, ...
]
```

My code is as follows:

```
const ToolSidebar = ({ sidebarTitle, tools }) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <List subheader={<ListSubheader>{sidebarTitle}</ListSubheader>}>
        {tools.forEach(tool => {
          return (
            <ListItem button href={tool.route}>
              <ListItemIcon>{tool.icon}</ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={tool.text} />
            </ListItem>
          );
        })}
      </List>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

UPDATE: For anyone who may stumble on this answer, while unrelated to the question, you will still get an error. Instead of:

```
<ListItemIcon>{tool.icon}</ListItemIcon>
```

use

```
<ListItemIcon> <SvgIcon component={tool.icon} /> </ListItemIcon>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `Array.prototype.map` not `Array.prototype.forEach`.

```js
{tools.map(tool => {
     return (
        <ListItem button href={tool.route}>
           <ListItemIcon>{tool.icon}</ListItemIcon>
           <ListItemText primary={tool.text} />
        </ListItem>
    );
  })}
}
```